# A question about essential ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Let $I$ be a nonunital C*-algebra and $I\subset B(H)$ be any nondegenerate representation and define
>   $$M(I)=\{T\in B(H): Tx\in I~and ~xT\in I,  ~for ~all~ x\in I\}.$$
>   Then,  how to prove $I$ sits in $M(I)$ as an essential ideal?

**Definition** An ideal $I\triangleleft E$ is *essential* if it has "no orthogonal complement" - i.e.,
$$I^{\bot}:=\{e\in E: ex=xe=0,~ for ~all~x\in I\}=\{0\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56394/non-degenerate-representations-for-c-algebras).

If $Tx=xT=0$ for every $x\in I$ then for every $h\in H$ we have $Txh=0$.

Now the set $\{xh,\ x\in I, h\in H\}$ is dense in $H$, since the representation is non-degenerate by the question above.

Since $\ker(T)$ is closed in $H$ and contains $\{xh,\ x\in I, h\in H\}$, which is dense in $H$ then $\ker(T)=H$ and $T=0$.

Comment: Thanks，Daniel. And I think your proof has nothing to do with the form of $M(I)$.

Comment: @Yankai You are welcome.